# Why do I have this weird reflections?

Tags: lighting, reflection

Why are those weird reflection on the edge of the blue driver appear. I didn't use any kind of glossy or metallic materials on it. How do I fix it?
Thank you in advance[image]

I added the project file
[image]

Comment: Can you upload your .blend file to https://blend-exchange.com/ ? Thanks.

Comment: It looks like stretching as a result of a subdivision surface modifier without adequate supporting geometry. Add an edge loop around the inside of the problematic "rim" and see what happens when you move it closer to one of the inner or outer rings - it should correct the image somewhat, but you may need to add a second edge loop to move close to the "other"  ring before it is fully corrected.

Comment: So... Any ideas? Or maybe it's just a bug